# Find the sum of values from distinct groups

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, distinct

I have a table like below.

| id | account_id | sha256 | size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | abc | 120 |
| 2 | 1 | abc | 120 |
| 3 | 1 | bcd | 150 |
| 4 | 2 | abc | 120 |
| 5 | 2 | def | 80 |
| 6 | 3 | fed | 100 |
| 7 | 3 | fed | 100 |

I need to find the sum of the size column but same sha256 for an account should be added only once. Rows to be added should as below.

| id | account_id | sha256 | size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | abc | 120 |
| 3 | 1 | bcd | 150 |
| 4 | 2 | abc | 120 |
| 5 | 2 | def | 80 |
| 6 | 3 | fed | 100 |

Row number 2 and 7 is removed due to duplicate sha256 value per same account. Row 4 is not removed as it belongs to a different account even though it has the same sha256, and sum should be 570.

Tried below query, but giving a syntax error at or near "distinct".

```
SELECT SUM(f.size) FROM 
(SELECT account_id, DISTINCT sha256, size FROM files GROUP BY account_id, sha256, size) f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT ON`:

```sql
SELECT SUM(size) AS total
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (account_id, sha256, size) size
    FROM FILES
    ORDER BY account_id, sha256, size, id
) t;
```

The above logic retains, for each group of `(account_id, sha256, size)` values, a single record corresponding to the lowest `id` value.  This set of records is then summed by size to get the total.

Answer (score 1):

You can sum over the distinct combinations of `account_id`, `sha256` and `size`:

```
SELECT SUM(size) total_size
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT account_id, sha256, size FROM files) f;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=48be5d953f86c9e7265e086e94f94128).

Answer (score 1):

your data

```
CREATE TABLE test(
   id         INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,account_id INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,sha256     VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
  ,size       INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO test
(id,account_id,sha256,size) VALUES 
(1,1,'abc',120),
(2,1,'abc',120),
(3,1,'bcd',150),
(4,2,'abc',120),
(5,2,'def',80),
(6,3,'fed',100),
(7,3,'fed',100);
```

use `Row_number` to distinguishing duplicate values

```
SELECT SUM(f.size) AS total
FROM   (SELECT id,
               account_id,
               sha256,
               size,
               Row_number ()
                 OVER (
                   partition BY account_id, sha256, size
                   ORDER BY id ASC ) rn
        FROM   test) f
WHERE  rn = 1
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a6f368e59dd0540597321a8b2ffecf38)

Answer (score 1):

Boils down to just:

```sql
SELECT sum(size) AS total
FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT ON (account_id, sha256) size FROM files) sub;
```

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

You didn't touch on the case where `size` would differ for the same `(account_id, sha256)`. I guess that's because that can never happen for some undisclosed reason. **If** it can happen, you need to define what to do exactly ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one..

```
WITH
    files AS
        (
            Select 1 "ID",  1 "ACCOUNT_ID", 'abc' "SHA256", 120 "SZ" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 2 "ID",  1 "ACCOUNT_ID", 'abc' "SHA256", 120 "SZ" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 3 "ID",  1 "ACCOUNT_ID", 'bcd' "SHA256", 150 "SZ" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 4 "ID",  2 "ACCOUNT_ID", 'abc' "SHA256", 120 "SZ" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 5 "ID",  2 "ACCOUNT_ID", 'def' "SHA256", 80 "SZ" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 6 "ID",  3 "ACCOUNT_ID", 'fed' "SHA256", 100 "SZ" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 7 "ID",  3 "ACCOUNT_ID", 'fed' "SHA256", 100 "SZ" From Dual 
        )
SELECT DISTINCT
    Min(f.ID) OVER(PARTITION BY f.ACCOUNT_ID, f.SHA256 ORDER BY f.ACCOUNT_ID, f.SHA256) "ID",
    f.ACCOUNT_ID "ACCOUNT_ID", 
    f.SHA256 "SHA256",
    f.SZ "SIZE"      
FROM 
    files f
ORDER BY 
    f.ACCOUNT_ID, 
    f.SHA256
--
--  Result
-- ID   ACCOUNT_ID  SHA256     SIZE
--  1           1   abc         120
--  3           1   bcd         150
--  4           2   abc         120
--  5           2   def          80
--  6           3   fed         100
```

Min(f.ID) OVER(.....)  is the first ID of group (ACCOUNT_ID, SHA256), DISTINCT gives us just distinct rows and the rest are values that you asked for. If you sum the size you'll get 570... Regards...